# df.isna().sum() is not working on titanic dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried titanic model on kaggle. And it is weird that isna().sum() outputs wrong information.

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

worksheet = gc.open('titanic_train').sheet1

titanic = worksheet.get_all_records()
titanic = pd.DataFrame(titanic)
titanic
```

```
titanic.info()
titanic.isna().sum()
```

output is like below.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   PassengerId  891 non-null    int64  
 1   Survived     891 non-null    int64  
 2   Pclass       891 non-null    int64  
 3   Name         891 non-null    object 
 4   Sex          891 non-null    object 
 5   Age          891 non-null    object 
 6   SibSp        891 non-null    int64  
 7   Parch        891 non-null    int64  
 8   Ticket       891 non-null    object 
 9   Fare         891 non-null    float64
 10  Cabin        891 non-null    object 
 11  Embarked     891 non-null    object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(5), object(6)
memory usage: 83.7+ KB
```

```
PassengerId    0
Pclass         0
Name           0
Sex            0
Age            0
SibSp          0
Parch          0
Ticket         0
Fare           0
Cabin          0
Embarked       0
dtype: int64
```

It said that NaN is 0 but there are several NaN in Age, Embarked. Why it cant detect Nan? Is it because of Dtype??

Answer (score 0):

It is doing this because there are no `NaNs`

You notice the `df.info()`
there is no null value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but in titanic_train.csv has null value. I can see many empty cells on the spreadsheet but df.info() is not showing that null value. Thats the problem right now.

Comment: I got the data set from kaggle site and train.csv has 891 rows. www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=train.csv

Comment: Yes the original has 891 values and it also has null values

Comment: I just downloaded the data , I can not understand why it is not recognising null values. Maybe because you are using google colab: try using the csv directly

Comment: Yes that is really wired. It certainly contains null values but isna() and info() is not showing them. Is it because I import data from google spreadsheet? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It is my assumption that it could be due to google colab because when I do it directly with csv then it works good

Answer (score 0):

its because of your panda version is 1.2.4.when i degrade to .24 or some other lower version you will get nan values

Answer (score 0):

I imported in Google Colab as well and get the follwing output when running `df.isna().sum()`:

```
PassengerId      0
Survived         0
Pclass           0
Name             0
Sex              0
Age            177
SibSp            0
Parch            0
Ticket           0
Fare             0
Cabin          687
Embarked         2
dtype: int64
```

Did you make any column conversions? For instance, setting the Age column to type object will convert any **np.nan** values to **"nan"** which are not recognised as missing values by pandas.

```
df["Age"] = df["Age"].astype(str)

df["Age"].isna().sum()
# output: 0
```

You can check for any "nan" values with this:

```
df["Age"].str.contains("nan").any()
# output: True
```

Converting them back to np.nan will solve the issue:

```
df["Age"].replace("nan", np.nan, inplace=True)
```

```
df["Age"].isna().sum()
# output: 177
```